# Get and use the translator in form definition UserType.php

Tags: symfony

I have a class `UserType.php` user registration. Translations of labels happen without problems, but not translated `invalid_message`.

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'translate.label.name'))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'translate.label.email'))
            ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'first_name' => 'password',
                'second_name' => 'confirm',
                'invalid_message' => 'translate.invalid.message.password.match',
                'first_options'   => array('label' => 'translate.label.password'),
                'second_options'  => array('label' => 'translate.label.repeat.password'),
            ))
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'translate.label.sign.up'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Digisolution\UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'digisolution_userbundle_usertype';
    }
}
```

if I make this same form, my controller error can be translated with:

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('translate.invalid.message.password.match')
```

but in my `UserType` you cannot access the translator with `$ this-> get ('translator')`

What class do I have to instantiate in `UserType.php` to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Declare your form type as a service, inject the `translator` service and use it like this:

```
...
'invalid_message' => $this->translator->trans('translate.invalid.message.password.match', HERE_GO_OPTIONAL_PARAMETERS),
...
```

Actually `$this->get()` method just calls the specified service, e.g. `$this->get('translator')` - is just returning a translator service from the service container.

Also, better way would be to put the validation error messages into the `validators.*.yml` file, because of validation errors are translated in the validators translation domain, but looks like [there are some issues](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6763) I think

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVE: in the controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType($this->get('translator')), $user);
```

Passing the translator instance work just fine

in the form class:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType{
private $translator;
public function __construct($translator){
    $this->translator =$translator;
}
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$translator = $this->translator;
$builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'translate.label.name'))
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'translate.label.email'))
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'first_name' => 'password',
            'second_name' => 'confirm',
            'invalid_message' => $translator->trans('translate.invalid.message.password.match'),
            'first_options'   => array('label' => 'translate.label.password'),
            'second_options'  => array('label' => 'translate.label.repeat.password'),
        ))
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Labels are already automatically translated.

Comment: Yes, this work just fine!, the problem is with invalid_message, is no a label, i want get the translator inside of my UserType class to translate directy